# Drawing a Large Vertically and Horizontally Symmetrical X to Cross Out Just the Contents of a Page

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, diagrams

I am encountering some problems trying to draw a "big X" to give the effect of crossing out the contents of a single page.

The top part of the X is essentially where I would like it (although the `vspace*` command does not give consistent results here), but the bottom of the X always seems to span the width of the page instead of the width of the text.

This may not be the optimal way to accomplish the objective, but here's what I have:

The code

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 8.25in \textwidth 5.75in

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{A TITLE TO GO ALONG WITH THE TEXT THAT I WOULD LIKE TO BE PART OF WHAT THE 'X' CROSSES OUT}}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}


\vskip 15pt

\large


\lipsum[1-4]\vspace*{-400pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, black]
        ([yshift=-85pt]current page.south east) -- ([yshift=-310pt, xshift=85pt]current page.north west);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, black]
    ([yshift=-85pt]current page.south west) -- ([yshift=-310pt, xshift=-85pt]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

QUESTION: How may I draw a big X so that the contents of the page are *neatly* crossed out? Is there a more tractable alternative to the code I posted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tikzpagenodes` package and its `current page text area`. (Note: you need to run this twice)

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 8.25in \textwidth 5.75in
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}%<--

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{A TITLE TO GO ALONG WITH THE TEXT THAT I WOULD LIKE TO BE PART OF WHAT THE 'X' CROSSES OUT}}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\vskip 15pt
\large
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, black]
   (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.south east);%<--
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, cap=round, black]
    (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.south west);%<--
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]